# bat file executing files against DB from folder

Tags: sql, batch-file, ingres

I have Ingres DB and I keep all my procedures files in folder, if i need to rebuild them on DB. There is a lot of procedures which related to eachohter (called one from another), so that  mean ai have to run some proceudre first  then run other.  Right now I am using bat file in which I have to supply file name, and it taking forefer to do it  by hands one by one. To do it I am using  this bat file.

```
echo '' > sqlout
more sqlout
set /p database="Enter database:"
if "%database%"=="" set database=1507
CALL C:\"Program Files"\Ingres\..\..\bin\setingenvs.bat
set directory_name=DBProcs
:While

set /p filename="Enter Procedure Filename:"
echo %filename%
sql DBServerName::%database% -udba <D:\Php_Web_Source\..\DBProcs\%filename% > sqlout
more sqlout
set /p another="Do you have another? (Y/N)"
if "%another%"=="N" goto EndWhile
goto While
:EndWhile
```

I want to it just run bat  file and it should run all files in folder, but not sure how to do it. I was thinking about something like for loop, which call exist bat for each file in folder, but  do not  know how to do it, any help appreciated

Comment: Hi Andrey, I'm a bit curious about your usage of pathes. `..` in a path means one level up - so `C:\"Program Files"\Ingres\..\..\bin\setingenvs.bat` is the same as `C:\bin\setingenvs.bat` !  Same with `D:\Php_Web_Source\..\DBProcs\%filename%` resolves to `D:\DBProcs\%filename%` or is this a method of obfuscating the code?

Comment: yes, the paht is long  i juzt  make it  shorter for here :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate all the files in a directory it is a basic for loop.

```
for %%G IN (C:\mypath\*.*) do echo %%G
```

The %%G will be the path with the file name in this instance.  You can then run any command with that variable.

Comment: stil dont understand how to call my exist batch file for each file, could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Andrey, I know nothing about databases.  I assumed you were going to replace your SET /P command. `set /p filename="Enter Procedure Filename:"`

Comment: dont care about  procedure I nee to call other batch file which i have in my question, and pass there file name as parameter. but  just dont  understand  how

Comment: @Andrey, the code Squashman has given you essentially replaces the part of your script where you set %filename%, allowing you to run all files in a set of folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't often add new files which need to be run, then one option would be to simply write a single sql file which calls all of your other scripts.

For example:

```
\cd D:\Php_Web_Source\..\DBProcs\
\read proc1.sql
\read proc2.sql
\read proc3.sql
```

You can also create this script fairly quickly by getting a list of all your files and then using a tool such as Notepad++ to do a quick find and replace

```
dir/b *.sql > files.txt
```

Would give you a list of all sql files in a single directory (you can adjust the command if you need multiple directories). Then using a Regex search and replace

```
\r\n
```

with

```
\r\n\\read
```

would get you what you need.

As I said, this is a quick method if your files don't change to often or as a quick and dirty method. Squashman's answer is more correct for a regularly changing file structure.